# Wrong ID and missing attributes in "Change Password" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, user-interface, login

Some suggestions on the Change Password page:

Current password:

- Label above the field has the `for="password"` attribute.
- But the ID of the input is "currentpassword" instead, which leads to highlighting the wrong field when clicking the heading:

[image: Clicking the top heading in the change password flow highlights the wrong field]

New password & New password (again):

- It would be great to use the attribute `autocomplete="new-password"` in order to prevent password managers from autofilling these fields with the old password.

  - Please see [Preventing autofilling with autocomplete="new-password"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

Comment: It never would have occurred to me that the labels could be clicked in order to focus a corresponding input field.

Answer (score 2):

Great suggestion for preventing autofilling, I added that to the change and fixed the attribute, so it highlights the correct input field.

Thanks for bringing this up and since autofilling can work differently on browsers or with different password managers, let us know if the change needs tweaking.